# F-Droid java.io.FileNotFoundException / won't update

Tags: installation, owncloud, f-droid

I'm having the problem, that **I can't**

- **install a new app** from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/), instead I get

  > java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...
- **update my package sources**, I get something like

  > unknown error

([F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) is an "installable catalogue of FOSS (Free and Open Source Software) applications for the Android platform.")

In detail:

- I'm using Android 4.2.2 on a FairPhone 1
- I want to install the [OwnCloud synchronization client](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.owncloud.android).
- my error message when trying to install the client from F-droid:

  > java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
  >   http://f-droid.org/repo/com.owncloud.android_10500800.apk

What can I do to install the app from F-Droid (to benefit from the updating service)?

Comment: Also: F-Droid isn't updating any other apps. Neither automatically nor on my button press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved my problem was:

1. I realized, that

   - the [OwnCloud synchronization client](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.owncloud.android) **is on version 1.7.2** on the webpage,
   - while my F-Droid **tries to download version 1.5.8**
   - on the F-Droid webpage there is **no version 1.5.8** for the OwnCloud client 
      
     (which may have resulted in the "File not found" exception)
2. I forced my **package sources**/repository to **reload** 
   (by changing my repository address to something invalid and back to original and then "update")
3. I **could install** the up-to-date [OwnCloud client](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.owncloud.android) **in version 1.7.3** (*voila!*)

**Edit:**

On F-Droid 0.96.1 it appears you can't edit existing repositories. You'll have to replace **2.** above by

> 2. I forced my **package sources**/repository to **reload** 
>      (e.g. by removing the "F-Droid" archive (note the URL) and re-adding it)

Comment: After this F-Droid is again offering updates for installed apps.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem by uninstalling F-Droid and installing it new via the browser (as I don't know how to change the repository address).

Comment: That's odd - on the current version of F-Droid (0.96.1) the functionality to change repositories is missing. I'll update my answer. In F-Droid you can add new repositories by {options key}->repositories->{plus sign}